# How to cancel onGoing notification?

Tags: java, android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications

I have created notification for my events. Now I want to cancel the onGoing notification if user has deleted some events. So the notification should not occur. I have created notification receiver with broadcast receiver.

Also I want to update the notification if user wants to change the time of notification.

How can I do this?

Here is NotificationReceiver :

```
public class NotificationReceiver  extends BroadcastReceiver {


public static int MY_NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;
NotificationManager notificationManager;
Notification myNotification;

EventTableHelper db;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    Toast.makeText(context, "Time is set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    db = new EventTableHelper(context);

    List<EventData> testSavings = db.getAllEvents();

    for (EventData ts : testSavings) {
        String log = "from date:" + ts.getFromDate()
                + " ,to date: " + ts.getToDate()
                + " ,location: " + ts.getLocation()
                + " ,title " + ts.getTitle();

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date date = new Date();
        Date date1 = new Date();
        Log.d("Result: ", log);

        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
        SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");

        try {
            date = df.parse(ts.getFromDate());
            date1 = df.parse(ts.getToDate());
        } catch (ParseException ex) {

        }
        String timeFrom = df2.format(date);
     //   String startTime = String.valueOf(timeFrom);

        String timeTo = df2.format(date1);
       // String endTime = String.valueOf(timeTo);


        String location = ts.getLocation();
        String title = ts.getTitle();


        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                context,
                0,
                myIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        if(location.equals(""))
        {
            String msg = "From : " + timeFrom + "\nTo : " + timeTo;

            myNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setContentTitle("Event : " + title)
                    .setContentText(msg)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.eventicon)
                    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                    .build();

        }

        else
        {
            String msg = "From : " + timeFrom + "\nTo : " + timeTo + "\nAt : " + location;
            myNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setContentTitle("Event : " + title)
                    .setContentText(msg)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.eventicon)
                    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                    .build();

        }

        Log.i("Notify", "Notification");
        notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, myNotification);

        myNotification.flags=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        MY_NOTIFICATION_ID ++;

    }
}
```

}

Creating notification using an alarm manager.

```
 public void notificationOnDay(Calendar c)
{

    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),NotificationReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,c.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY *7, pendingIntent);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can cancel your repeating alarm to avoid notification. When you set a new alarm. Assign it a unique id so when you want to cancel the alarm you can cancel it like this

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReciever.class);
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, alarm_id_to_cancel, intent, 0);
am.cancel(sender);
```

Comment: I have multiple alarms to be raised how to set ids? How will it delete the same alarm of a deleted event?

Comment: I have RQS_1 as id in alarm manager. So will this call multiple alarms for multiple events? Or it will overlap the other alarm?

Comment: If you assign the same id to multiple alarms, it will overlap the existing alarm with the same id. So assign different ids to alarms. So that you can cancel when you want.

Comment: If you want to see example of alarm manager. You can see my repo [here](https://github.com/asadhaider13/AlarmManagerExample). I have implemented alarm manager with boot receiver which reset the alarms if device is reboot.